# Multiple Validation checks - logic error

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am providing a validation feature on a form for passwords. I need to be able to implement a few validation rules and have them all checked on submit. Now to me the code is sound but I think they may be some logic error in my code that I'm too tired to notice (too the coffee machine!)

Here's the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function validate(registerForm)
    registerForm.onsubmit=function()
    {
        var pw1 = document.forms["register"]["password1"].value;
        var pw2 = document.forms["register"]["password2"].value;

        //Check values are present in both fields
        if(pw1 == '' || pw2 == '')
        {
            alert("Please enter your password twice.");
            return false;
        }
        //Check there no spaces
        else if(document.forms["register"]["password1"].value.indexOf(invalid) > - 1) 
        {
            alert("Spaces are not allowed in passwords!");
            return false;
        }
        //Check passwords are the same
        else
        {
            if(pw1 != pw2) 
            {
                alert("The passwords you entered were not the same. Please try again!");
                return false;
            }
            //Accept passwords
            {
                alert("Password accepted!");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
-->
</script>
```

And the HTML Form to go with it:

```
<form id="register">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="input_text" name="username" id="name" placeholder="e.g. AberLibrary01" />
    <br />
    <label for="password">Password</label> 
    <input type="text" class="input_text" name="password1" id="password1" placeholder="e.g. aber01" />
    <br />
    <label for="re-enterpassword">Re-enter password</label>
    <input type="text" class="input_text" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="e.g. aber01" />

    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Register" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        new validate(document.forms['register']);
    -->
    </script>
```

Any ideas of lovely StackOverflow community? The exact problem is that it won't check for spaces in passwords or whether two passwords entered are the same. It successfully checks that there is at least something in both password fields.

Thanks Dan

Comment: I forgot to mention it successfully checks that there is something within the password fields but doesn't check whether there are spaces or that both passwords match each other!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
else if(document.forms["register"]["password1"].value.indexOf(invalid) > - 1)
```

`invalid` is not defined and I suspect this will cause the problems you're facing.

Comment: Ahh thank you! Fixed my problem instantly been in work since 8am, eyes are tired =]

Comment: No it doesn't solve your problem, there are many more errors. For example " " and "hdhadhadh" when entered are accepted. And passwords are not checked if they are equal or not.

Comment: A new problem has arisen: the validation works perfectly in Firefox but not in Chrome and IE9, JavaScript is enabled on both, any ideas? :/

Comment: Can you edit your question with the new code. Also what is the error(s)

Comment: The code is still the same, its just not working in IE9 or Google Chrome, the form just submits all the fields even if they're empty, but it works fine in Firefox :/

Comment: Is there meant to be a brace between these two lines `function validate(registerForm)
    registerForm.onsubmit=function()`

Answer (score 0):

Made changes to your code got it working http://jsbin.com/igonec/edit#preview

ERRORS

1. Use of var pw1 = document.forms["register"]["password1"]. It was causing errors
2. Missing else.
3. Use of invalid instead of " ".
4. Wrong use of brackets.

I omitted your errors and made the solution more elegant.

Javascipt

```
    function validate()
     {
        var pw1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
        var pw2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;

        //Check values are present in both fields
        if(pw1 ==='' || pw2 === '')
        {
            alert("Please enter your password twice.");
            return false;
        }
        //Check there no spaces
        else if(document.getElementById("password1").value.indexOf(" ") > - 1) 
        {
            alert("Spaces are not allowed in passwords!");
            return false;
        }
        //Check passwords are the same
        else
        {
            if(pw1 !== pw2) 
            {
                alert("The passwords you entered were not the same. Please try again!");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Password accepted!");
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
```

HTML

```
<form id="register">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="input_text" name="username" id="name" placeholder="e.g. AberLibrary01" />
    <br />
    <label for="password">Password</label> 
    <input type="text" class="input_text" name="password1" id="password1" placeholder="e.g. aber01" />
    <br />
    <label for="re-enterpassword">Re-enter password</label>
    <input type="text" class="input_text" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="e.g. aber01" />

    <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="validate()" value="Register" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I will bear these mind but the answer above has solved my problem. :)

Comment: Your problems have not yet been solved. There are many more errors, for example, passwords are not matched, any ways, your welcome.

Comment: if I enter two different passwords my validation message is produced saying they don't match. To me that is successful validation, there's more than one way to skin a cat friend.

Comment: I copied your code to jsFiddle with the changes you accepted, its not working. http://jsfiddle.net/FjrZj/2/ , you are even missing "else", I don't know how its working for you.

Comment: you don't need an "else" because javascript is a very loose language. I have added the else as a form of good practice but apart from that the JavaScript has been tested and works. Don't alwasy rely on jsFiddle! =]